# What is the proper substitute for "Batmanning"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

After planking, owling and leisure dive, now there is the trend which is called "Batmanning". Obviously it is a made-up word. Is there a proper substitute for it? What is the verb that defines the act when a bat hangs from somewhere?

Comment: Doesn't your question answer itself? The verb when a bat hangs somewhere is "hang". Or are you looking for a one-word synonym for the verb phrase "hang upside-down"?

Comment: @Peter: The latter. That's why I tagged my question as _single-word-requests_.

Comment: Yes, I saw the tag, but since "hang" is already a single word...

Comment: @Peter: I thought there would be a verb to distinguish _upside down_ from _upright_...

Comment: (Bah! Batman does *not* hang upside-down like that.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Planking" is just as incorrect as "Batmanning" other than the spellchecker is okay with it for unrelated reasons. If the masses of the internet feel like coining a term that compares 'hanging like a bat' to 'planking' then so be it. The same goes for "owling".

Assuming you meant a word that just means, "hanging upside down":

- roost
- perch
- hang
- suspend
- dangle

There isn't usually a way to distinguish "upside down" from "upright" positions with these but context generally helps:

> He hung from the rafters.

Comment: If the masses of the internet feel like using “than” when they mean “then,” _then_ so be it. :)

Comment: Yeah, I still haven't been able to figure out an easy way to remember which is which. :P

Answer (score 4):

Teenage trends are all about being different from the oldies, and I am sure the 'Batmanners' would be mortified to find that there already was a word for the activity they have invented.  That said, I think they are fairly safe in assuming "hanging upside down like a bat while somebody takes a picture of you" is not popular enough to have a single-word synonym.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the boots they use with hooks to keep you hanging on a bar like that are called "inversion boots". They were popular back in the 80's after Richard Gere used them in a movie (don't tell the kids this).

If you want a technical term for the act of using inversion boots, it would be `inversion`.

Answer (score 2):

You might describe it as [*resupinate*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/resupinate). Although *resupination* means to appear upside-down, I think in a human context, the hanging part would be implied.